# C# datagridview and mysql simultaneous update

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Im new in c# windows form application, 
using a datagridview and insert its values into a mysql table, when i retrieve it and make some changes i also want those changes on the Mysql table ..

Comment: You need to write an `UPDATE` query

Comment: @Cid yes .. update is working fine, but when i delete the row on datagridview i also what it out on mysql table .. any tip how can i associate the delete query to datagridview?

Comment: I recommend to also have a look at an ORM tool like nhibernate or entity framework. It takes some effort learning but it greatly simplifies database access.

Comment: @PeterEncinaresImboy then you need a `DELETE` query in that case

Comment: Best way of doing is to make a datatable the source of the DGV.  The rows of the DGV and datatable are the same.  So you can then change datatable and use the Accept changes to put results back into the database.  There are 4 types of commands 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Insert 4) Update.  For the accept changes to work you need all 4 commands.  Using a command builder will take the Select command and generate the other 3.  See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommandBuilder.htm